# Encryption & Decryption of username using KeyStore in Android M & older version?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, rsa, android-keystore

i'm trying to encrypt and decrypt username in app using KeyStore,

Using KeyPairGeneratorSpec to create the key in older version like 18 to 22,

**KeyPairGeneratorSpec as been *depricated* in version 23 of android M,
But Android M supports KeyGenParameterSpec.**

Does this KeyGenParameterSpec supports backward comparability or how do i do this ?

Im trying out some thing like this , is there any better solution for this.
This works fine as off now!

*At the time of Ciper.getInstance in encryption and Decryption i need to do this.
is there any single parameter "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding" or "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" i can pass for both the version* ?

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        }else{
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        }
```

**Below code works fine as off now , let me know how do i improve this.**

Key Generator :

```
genkey(){
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                TCLog.e(TAG,"Current version is 23(MashMello)");
                //Api level 23

                KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new  KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                             keyName,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT )
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                            .build();
                generator.initialize(spec);
            }else{
                TCLog.e(TAG,"Current version is < 23(MashMello)");
                //api level 17+ 4.4.3
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setAlias(keyName)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
                generator.initialize(spec);
            }
           KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Encryption code :

```
doEncription(){
 try {
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(keyName, null);
        PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
        Cipher c;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        }else{
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        }

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        encodedUser = c.doFinal(userName.getBytes());
        encodedPassword = c.doFinal(userPassword.getBytes());

        userName = Base64.encodeToString(encodedUser, Base64.DEFAULT);
        userPassword = Base64.encodeToString(encodedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT);
        // Log.e("MainActivity","AES Encription Error.!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "AES Encription Error.!");
    }
}
```

Decryption Code :

```
doDecryption(){
    try {
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(keyName, null);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();

        Cipher c;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        }else{
            c =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        }
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        decodedUser = c.doFinal(encodedUser);
        decodedPassword = c.doFinal(encodedPassword);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "AES Decryption Error.!");
    }

}
```

Comment: @nikolay-elenkov could you please quick look at this code? is it safe for ciphering sensitive data?

Comment: can you tell me a link where can i find the full code or where you get the code?

Answer (score 5):

the cypher transformation depends on what parameters you give to `KeyGenParameterSpec` or `KeyPairGeneratorSpec`.
If you want to use `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` in both cases (Android M and below) change

```
spec.setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
```

to

```
spec.setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
```

You can check which algorithms are available with the following piece of code:

```
    Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
    for (Provider p : providers) {
        Log.d(TAG, "provider: " + p.getName());
        Set<Provider.Service> services = p.getServices();
        for (Provider.Service s : services) {
            Log.d(TAG, "--> algorithm: " + s.getAlgorithm());
        }
    }
```

I avoided writing a lot of if-else by declaring an interface IKeyStoreHandler which provides all the necessary methods (add / remove keys, list all keys by their aliases, get private / public key, decrypt / encrypt text) and implementing it for both cases.