# Decrypting message with RSA-OAEP and Android Keystore: IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: android, rsa, android-keystore

I have the following code inside a `try` block that should generate a RSA public/private keypair use the public key to encrypt a message and decrypt again with the private key:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
         KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                 "key1",
                 KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
                 .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                 .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                 .build());
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
byte[] src = "hello world".getBytes();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(src);

Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
byte[] msg = cipher2.doFinal(cipherData);
```

Taken mostly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33754129) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec#example:-rsa-key-pair-for-encryptiondecryption-using-rsa-oaep).

The final line throws an exception of type `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException` with no message/further details. The three lines in `logcat` before the exception are

```
 E keymaster1_device: Finish send cmd failed
 E keymaster1_device: ret: 0
 E keymaster1_device: resp->status: -1000
```

in case that matters at all.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Using `minSdkVersion 23`

Edit:
I just realised, if I use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding it works. That helps me for now, but I'd still like to try get it work with OAEP.

Comment: @kelalaka `minSdkVersion` is 23

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Diederikjh/36ae22d5fde9d8f671a70b5d8cada90e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put into the cipher the algorithm parameter spec when you encrypt

```
if (algorithmParameterSpec != null) {
            encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey(), algorithmParameterSpec)
        }
```

algorithmParameterSpec is

```
OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
                    "MGF1",
                    MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256,
                    PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: thanks for the update, that helped me: providing the specs as you suggested gives me a better error, `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported`, when I change `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256` to `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1` my code works.

Comment: try setting the cipher transformation to ```KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA + "/"
                    + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB + "/" 
                    + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP```
i.e : ```Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA + "/" 
                    + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB + "/" 
                    + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)```

Comment: instead of going to Sha1, because sha1 is breakable

Comment: Using `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256` on Android will not work, because the OS doesn't support it as @matec saw in the error. Changing the transformation won't make a difference.

Comment: well i have a working app with this line and it works just fine... what specifically doesnt work for you ?

Comment: Decrypting (`Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`) or unwrapping (`Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE`) an input using those parameters will result in the error message that was mentioned. Encryption (`Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`) works fine.

Comment: @LenaBru I'm facing the same issue.

 val spec = OAEPParameterSpec(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KEY_MGF_NAME,
                    MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)

private const val KEY_MGF_NAME = "MGF1"